# Is it explained how a person can fit in a Dalek?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

It has been used as a plot device in many episodes of Dr Who that a person will impersonate a Dalek by getting inside the travel machine, from the earliest series ("The Daleks", "Planet of the Daleks") through to more recent series ("Asylum of the Daleks", "The Witch's Familiar").

But, how is this possible? The inside of the Dalek has been repeatedly shown since the ninth Doctor's episode "Dalek", and the Dalek creature is much smaller than an average person (this was even hinted at in the first Doctor story "The Daleks").

Comment: Perhaps they are Tardis-like?

Comment: I guess if you remove the lifesupport for the Dalek creature you get some free space.

Comment: Where exactly has a *full-grown human body* been in a Dalek?

Comment: In the first Doctor story "The Daleks" (Ian), "Planet of the Daleks" (Rebec) and Clara in the two stories mentioned.

Comment: Bearing in mind that *in reality* daleks often have people inside....

Comment: http://www.cultbox.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Doctor-Who-William-Hartnell-in-Dalek.jpg

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/gJSsY

Comment: Take off their hats! No, that’s Popes in a Volkswagen...

Comment: @Paul.DWaite - Two in the front, two in the back and one in the glove box. No, that's elephants in a mini

Comment: Don't forget "Daleks in Manhattan". There seems to be just enough room for a human to fit, even though the Dalek creatures have always appeared to be much smaller.

Comment: Well, Clara is kind of short. I guess Amy, for example, wouldn't fit inside the Dalek.

Comment: ["Inside a Dalek"](http://66.media.tumblr.com/9a948b0a252c2bec9e1d88fc784e154a/tumblr_mqwoqh8ywi1qztcdbo1_1280.jpg) - 'Doctor Who and The Daleks Omnibus’ (1976)

Comment: Must... not... mention... "Into the Dalek"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best evidence we have on the subject is from the recent "[The Witch's Familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witch%27s_Familiar)" episode in which we see Clara sitting in a Dalek shell.

[image]

In the prior scene we see Missy removing the football-sized Dalek from its armour. The next scene (which we don't see) presumably involved both of them ripping out the Dalek's life-support mechanism and other, now unnecessary workings from the inside of the case, leaving a void and a small seat for Clara to perch on.

We also see inside another Dalek in [Daleks in Manhattan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daleks_in_Manhattan). Although this design is different, again, there's clearly more than enough space for a fully grown adult.

[image]

---

There are no end of "Official" Dalek anatomies to choose from, but the common factor in all of them is that **the majority of the internal 'organs' within the armour shell are not integral to the armour itself, but there to aid the inhabitant.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Out of universe, there's clearly more than enough room in a Dalek to fit an average-sized production staffer. Someone as small as Jenna Coleman (5ft 2) wouldn't have any difficulty whatsoever.

[image]